# How to know if user is in checkout?

Tags: magento, checkout

In Magento I have an observer which listens to the `sales_order_save_before` event. This event is called before the order is saved. This happens in the checkout before the success site AND in the backend if you save the order there.

I only want the logic to run in the checkout not in the backend. So, how can I check in my observer if the user is in the checkout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined your observer in

```
<config>
    <global></global>
<config>
```

If you define it in

```
<config>
    <frontend></frontend>
<config>
```

is only runs in frontend.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this out?
http://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-programming/633-events-with-magento-checkout

and this,
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/events

here is a great events cheatsheet,
http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/